# Python: How do I convert every letter to a lowercase using a for loop?

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, methods, conditional-statements

In this exercise, I have to check each letter in a word using a for loop and at the same time also check if the letter exists in the dictionary.  However, I have to make every letter lowercase for the letters to add up to the total value correctly. I tried using the .lower() function before checking if the letters are in the dictionary, but I seemed to have made a stupid mistake somewhere. The dictionary looks like this: letter_value_dict = {"r": 2, "s": 2, "h":4, "t":3, "m": 7, "g":4, "v":8}

```
def get_text_valuation(letter_worth_dict, text): #generate a sum total value using this function
    value = 0
    for letter in text:
        letter.lower()
        if letter.isalpha() == True: 
            if not letter in letter_worth_dict:
                value += 1
            elif letter in letter_worth_dict:
                value += letter_worth_dict[letter]

    return value
```

Comment: The `lower` string method doesn't change the string (in fact, it can't, because strings are immutable).  It *returns* the new string.  So you need `letter = letter.lower()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

letter.lower() returns a new String (it doesn't affect the letter String)

```
def get_text_valuation(letter_worth_dict, text): #generate a sum total value using this function
    value = 0
    for letter in text:
        letter=letter.lower()
        if letter.isalpha() == True: 
            if not letter in letter_worth_dict:
                value += 1
            elif letter in letter_worth_dict:
                value += letter_worth_dict[letter]

    return value
```